# How can I execute a transaction from a smart contract without any human interaction?

Tags: solidity, web3js, smart-contract-wallets

I'd like to write a smart contract that holds X funds, and when a certain condition is met on-chain, transfers them to a predefined address, paying for gas from the contract balance.

Is it possible for a smart contract to "self execute" in this manner?

If not, is it possible to set a limit on how much gas the user (web3 wallet) pays, with the remainder (or all) coming from the smart contract balance?

I figure the solution lies in having a second "helper" contract that calls the main contract and pays for the gas - but how can I set that helper contract to execute automatically on a regular basis?

Comment: Not possible to have self execute. There are some people do it for you and they are called keepers . Chain link has it’s own trusted keeper network that trigger contract for you but u need to read more about it and add interface and code in your contract

Answer (score 1):

You can look into OpenZeppelin's [Defender](https://openzeppelin.com/defender/) and set [Autotasks](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/defender/autotasks), according to their doucmentation:

> The Defender Autotasks service allows you to run code snippets on a regular basis, via webhooks, or in response to a transaction. Thanks to tight integration to Relay and Sentinels, you can use Autotasks to automate regular actions by easily sending transactions or reacting to events from your contracts.

I think this will serve you to self execute, since onced configured they run on their own.